# How do you decide where to place a filler?

Tags: fiction, creative-writing

Examples:

> "I've always been interested in marine biology, **as far as I can
> remember**.
>
> "**As far as I can
> remember**, I've always been interested in marine biology,
>
> ---
>
> **Of course**, we can't just set all criminals free.
>
> We can't just set all criminals free, **of course**.

Maybe a good rule is to put them at the beginning if the main sentence is long, and at the end if the main sentence is short?

Comment: I think this belongs on the English Language & Usage site: http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Nicole: One could take the question that way, but not necessarily.  See my answer.

Comment: @Nicole it might also fit there, but it seems like a question about style and not just strict grammar, so I think it fits here too.

Answer (score 5):

You (usually) should put the thing first that you want to emphasize.  But speech can be different, since it is also characterization.

A hesitant or unsure character might habitually tack qualifiers to the ends of his statements.

> "A dog is a mammal, I think."
>
> "People should be nice to children, I suppose."
>
> "If you take one step closer I'll shoot you -- and don't think I won't, because I will.  I'll shoot you; I'm not kidding."

A very logical person might habitually preface his statements with qualifiers.

> "According to folklore, Santa lives at the North Pole."
>
> "Most societies would say your mother is worthy of respect."
>
> "Considering your past betrayals, I'll slit your throat if you even
>   twitch."

And, of course, a muddle-headed (or brilliant) person will habitually have qualifiers all over his statements.

> It has been said, perhaps with some overstatement, that love -- that
>   is, "romantic love" -- conquers all.
>
> I know he's lying, because he said he petted a penguin at the North
>   Pole, and penguins live only at the South Pole -- or, more properly,
>   in the southern reaches of the southern hemisphere.
>
> I'm sure everyone would agree that Aunt Betty, God rest her soul, was
>   the best seamstress in the northwest suburbs of Dubuque, or at least
>   one of the top five still living as of three days ago.

Answer (score 4):

Think about what fillers are used for. They can be habitual. For example, some people start every utterance with 'well'. Mostly, they are used to give the person a little bit more time to think. Work out when your character most needs that time (at the beginning because they don't know what to say or half way through because they don't know what to say next) and then place them there.

One thing to be careful of: Don't overuse them. Remember you are trying to represent real life, not copy it exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Filler is just like metadiscourse. Don't use them, just get straight to your point.

Comment: This would strip the prose of all style and make it hard to set the scene. While a bare-bones style like this might work for some, it's not going to work for everyone. But I'm willing to be convinced; If you're advocating a simple style, maybe you could expand on where and why it might be helpful?

Comment: I must actually agree with this answer (and have upvoted it). You should always avoid filler (if it is just filler). Your writing should only consist of what is relevant to your narrative. That said, of course phrases like those that Alexandro calls "filler" might well be at the core of what your story is about. For example, they might define the narrator's or a character's personality. But if they are just filler, they should go, because they water down the impact of the story or even destroy the characterization. Whether or not what Alexandro means is actually filler, I don't know.